Create Eigen Library as a Dynamic Library (.dll) in C++ Builder
I have a program that includes the Eigen Library and runs on C++ Builder.
I want to build this program into a Dynamic Library (.dll) and refer to: Create and use Static Library (.Lib) and Dynamic DLLs in C++ Builder to understand the process of creation and usage.
However, when I include #include <Eigen/Eigen> in the DLL Cpp and build it, I encounter:
[bcc32c Error] MathFunctions.h(1304): use of undeclared identifier 'fabsf'
[bcc32c Error] MathFunctions.h(1310): use of undeclared identifier 'fabs'
[bcc32c Error] MathFunctions.h(1318): use of undeclared identifier 'fabsl'
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(660): no member named 'expf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(671): no member named 'logf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(678): no member named 'log10f' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(681): no member named 'logf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(689): no member named 'sqrtf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(693): no member named 'powf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(696): no member named 'sinf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(699): no member named 'cosf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(702): no member named 'tanf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(705): no member named 'tanhf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(708): no member named 'asinf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(711): no member named 'acosf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(718): no member named 'floorf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(726): no member named 'ceilf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(730): no member named 'rintf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(733): no member named 'roundf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] Half.h(736): no member named 'fmodf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(494): no member named 'expf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(500): no member named 'logf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(506): no member named 'log10f' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(509): no member named 'logf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(512): no member named 'sqrtf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(515): no member named 'powf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(518): no member named 'sinf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(521): no member named 'cosf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(524): no member named 'tanf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(527): no member named 'asinf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(530): no member named 'acosf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(533): no member named 'atanf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(536): no member named 'sinhf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(539): no member named 'coshf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(542): no member named 'tanhf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(546): no member named 'asinhf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(549): no member named 'acoshf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(552): no member named 'atanhf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(556): no member named 'floorf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(559): no member named 'ceilf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(562): no member named 'rintf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(565): no member named 'roundf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(568): no member named 'fmodf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(585): no member named 'fminf' in the global namespace
[bcc32c Error] BFloat16.h(590): no member named 'fmaxf' in the global namespace
Failed

I want to know how to create a Dynamic Library (.dll) in C++ Builder and use the Eigen Library.
My Environment:

C++ Builder 11 CE
Eigen 3.4.0

This is my DLL cpp file, only include Eigen Library:
#include <Eigen/Eigen>

#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused


extern "C" double __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall Sum(double a, double b) {
    return a +b;
}

extern "C" int _libmain(unsigned long reason)
{
    return 1;
}


The missing methods seem to be methods which come from math.h, try adding an
#include <math.h>  so the methods can be found.

I have tried adding #include <math.h>, but it doesn't seem to be that straightforward to resolve. So I would like to ask if anyone has tried building a DLL using a program with the Eigen library.
